# Variable initiation inside curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, commonjs

What does this code translate to? I can't figure out how the variables inside the curly braces are related to `= require('react-router')`.

```
var { create: createRouter, HistoryLocation, HashLocation } = require('react-router')
```

It is from [this repo](https://github.com/gaearon/flux-react-router-example/blob/master/scripts/router.js)

Comment: Destructuring assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in ES6. This is what happens:

```
// Imagine this is the object you require
var reactRouter = {
  create: 'foo',
  HistoryLocation: 'bar',
  HashLocation: 'baz'
}

// Destructure
var {create: createRouter, HistoryLocation, HashLocation} = reactRouter

// Now the variables are in scope
console.log(createRouter, HistoryLocation, HashLocation)
//^ foo, bar, baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's **destructuring assignment**. It is a part of [Javascript ES6 and is described here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to extract data from arrays or objects using a syntax that mirrors the construction of array and object literals.

Cool new feature! I'm looking forward to using it.